# Python3 Sqllite Normal query works but not while passing it a tuple

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a Db from where I have to display all the columns which match the substring of the column given by user.
The following code works:

```
c.execute("select *from Transactions where Description like '%sh%' ")
conn.commit()
print(c.fetchall())
conn.close()
```

But when I try to run this code it returns me an empty list:

```
def search(col,val):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("Select *from Transactions where ? Like ? ",(col,'%'+val+'%'))
    print(c.fetchall())

search('description',"sh")
```

Also the result will always be a blank list even if the col name is wrong. as opposed the usual error which says column not found.

Please Help

Comment: You can't use a `?` placeholder for a column's name.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL. For example using an F-string: `c.execute(f"Select * from Transactions where {col} Like ? ",('%'+val+'%'))` (the column name variable is between curly braces).